# C Preprocessor: Evaluate macro early

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Consider the following setup:

**a.h**

```
#define A 5
#define B A
#undef A
#define A 3
```

**a.c**

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", B);
    return 0;
}
```

While this very reasonably prints 3, is there a way to make it print 5, i.e. do the substitution of 5 for A already at line two of a.h?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. I'll wait for someone more knowledgeable than me to prove me wrong.

Comment: These are not value assignments, but text substitution at the point of use. `A` never has the value 5 or 3, and `B` never equals 5, or 3.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the heads-up. I edited the wording accordingly.

Comment: You might consider changing a.h to `const int B = A;` instead of `#define B A` - that way it captures the value of `A` at that point in the compilation.  Another option is to use the non-Standard but widely implemented (gcc, clang, visual C++...) `#pragma push_macro("A")` to preserve the original value of `A`, then pop it before evaluating `B`, but that's fiddly and fragile.

Comment: No, there isn't such a way. Macro expansions are performed when the macro is used, not when it's defined.

Comment: `const int` works. https://ideone.com/MpiOOz

Comment: Do you have a real life use case for that ? I mean, I just can't think of one, (besides obfuscating code) .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that. Unless you know all the possible values of `A`, and they are always integers, in which case you can laboriously test each one in turn:

```
#if A == 0
# define B 0
#elif A == 1
# define B 1
#elif A == 2
# define B 2
/*  ... and a very long etc. */
#endif
```

If your use case only involves integers, you have more options. You could, for example, declare `B`to be `static const int` or `enum` (depending on language) instead of a macro, which would obviously use the current value of the macro. If you really really want macros, the Boost preprocessing library has an [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) of the laborious sequence of `#if`s above (with some cleverness to reduce the number of preprocessor statements needed to log(N) instead of N).

---

There is no macro substitution in the `#define` preprocessor directive; this fact is covered by §6.10 para. 7 of the C standard (§16 para. 6 of the C++ standard, with identical wording):

> The preprocessing tokens within a preprocessing directive are not subject to macro expansion unless otherwise stated.

In the description of the `#if` and `#include` directives, the standard specifies that macro replacement does occur, which is why the `#if` solution above works (and the Boost implementation, which also uses a computed `#include`).

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Boost's preprocessor library (a set of portable includes, not an extended preprocessor) includes [support for "mutable" macro definitions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/evaluated_slots.html). Instead of defining a macro to expand to a value directly, you can define it to expand to a reference a mutable slot, which can be changed because it expands the value "assigned" to it early. In this case you're less interested in the ability to change the value, than in the fact that this early expansion means it can grab the value out of `A` at a point ahead of both the use of `B` or the redefinition of `A`.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/slot.hpp>

#define A 5
#define B BOOST_PP_SLOT(1)

// "assign" A to B
#define BOOST_PP_VALUE A
#include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)

#undef A
#define A 3

#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", B);  // 5
    return 0;
}
```

Support is limited to integers. It takes advantage of the fact that `#if` directives force expansion of any contained macros (so do `#line` and `#error`, although those are not very useful for this purpose), and uses them to build up an *equivalent integer value* for the slot being assigned to, stored in hidden backend macros. This way it can "extract" a value from `A`, and `B` can then refer to the value itself even if `A` changes or is removed.

Comment: `#include BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)`... This is sick!  We don't need an obfuscated C++ code contest, we have boost!