# Forcing capture of C preprocessor macro value

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO_A "early"
#define MACRO_B MACRO_A
#undef MACRO_A
#define MACRO_A "late"
#define MACRO_C MACRO_A

int main(void) {
        printf("MACRO_B = %s, MACRO_C = %s\n", MACRO_B, MACRO_C);
        return 0;
}
```

I expected that MACRO_B would capture the value of MACRO_A at the time it was defined, namely "early".  But the above code prints:

```
MACRO_B = late, MACRO_C = late
```

Is there a way to force MACRO_B to capture the value of MACRO_A at the time it is defined?  (NB: In case of ambiguity, assume we're using `gcc`.)

My *real* use case is that I'm using a single macro form to create different expansions of a shared definition: one expansion defines the `struct` layout, a redefinition creates the initializers for the struct, etc.  This lets me keep all the info in one place.

For this reason, it would be useful to capture the "current" macro expansion in yet another macro so that I could re-use the original definition without losing its state.

Comment: No. Macro substitution happens with the current definitions only. It wouldn't be the C preprocessor otherwise.

Comment: Yep, it appears that this is truly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486726/c-preprocessor-evaluate-macro-early, and despite the focus on integers, it does a better job of answering the question.  Happy to delete this one...

Answer (score 0):

This kind of defeats the purpose of using macros. Macros should NOT be used for global variables.

One alternative is to use global variables. Instead of creating macros, use static global variables and set them to the value of the macros.

Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO_A "early"
static char* a = MACRO_A;
#define MACRO_B MACRO_A
static char* b = MACRO_B;
#undef MACRO_A
#define MACRO_A "late"
#define MACRO_C MACRO_A
static char* c = MACRO_C;

int main(void) {
        printf("MACRO_B = %s, MACRO_C = %s\n", a, c);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that's exactly how I'm using the macros.  I was just hoping that I didn't have to mix my .h files (macro definitions) with my .c files (macro expansions), if you get what I mean.  But I can restructure the code to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

As the C preprocessor only replaces text by other text, the following will happen when the `printf` line will be processed:

- `MACRO_B` will be replaced by the text `MACRO_A` as defined earlier;
- In a recursive way, `MACRO_A` will be replaced by its current definition: `"late"`

In the same way :

- `MACRO_C` will be replaced by `MACRO_A` as defined earlier;
- Then in a recursive way, `MACRO_A` will be replaced by `"late"`.